# How does Natsuki Subaru manage to stay mentally sane?

Tags: re-zero

After watching his friends die over and over again, how does Natsuki Subaru stay mentally sane?

For example: watching his friend die once may already have dire consequences on him. It may emotionally break him down. But repeating it over and over is insane! His perspective on friends could change and he may distance himself due to going through the death of his friends. But how does he remain so positive and mentally sane?

Comment: You're saying he remains positive and sane, but that's not true. If you look at what he does, half the time he's neurotic and doesn't really understand what he's doing and then regrets his actions and reflects on it.

Comment: Okay,sane as in he still have the will to live.Normally,if this happens to anyone in real life,we would probably just go crazy.I guess?

Comment: It's not as if his friends were dying all the time though. It has only happened a few times in the Anime. It's not as recurrent as in Steins;Gates for instance.

Comment: See Attack on Titan for friends dying all the time. Characters there are always on edge and very agitated. Sometimes they think there's no meaning to their life, but their buddies get them up and going again.

Comment: This seems like an opinion based question rather than one that can answered definitively

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** This contains spoilers toward recent episodes.

**The simple answer**: He doesn't.

**The more in depth one**:
He keeps up the farce of not being 'insane' by convincing himself that what he is doing is for a good cause, to "*save Emilia*". It's stated multiple times throughout the series by Subaru himself, that everything he is doing is for "*her sake*".
This gives him the motivation to keep his sanity to a certain point, though even he slips up at times, for example, when he wakes up in the bed before Ram and Rem, he appears sporadic and flustered, showing signs of being 'not sane.'

As we have seen in recent episodes (14 through 17), he has broken down his sane demeanor and become... as I'd like to put it: **A Sniveling Madman**. This is especially the case when he has to watch Rem mutilated before him (episode 15), as well as the moment in which he is infuriated at Otto (episode 16/early 17).